# Comedy SF radio show. Radio 4 or Radio 4 extra (UK) Aliens base their society on a book of Noel Coward's plays

Tags: story-identification, radio-play

I listened to it on the Radio in the UK between 2000 and 2015.

Humans are visiting a planet full of aliens. The aliens had been visited by humans once before. Their earlier human visitors left behind a book of plays by Noel Coward. The aliens spent many years decipering the meaning of the book and teaching themselves English.

The very imitative aliens had then based their entire culture on the contents of this book. I remember the aliens being incredibly keen on tennis.They spoke English like you hear upper class English characters in movies from the 1930s speak.

I believe there were several episodes each about 30 minutes long. I may have misremembered, maybe there was just a single episode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This must surely be *[Paradise Lost in Space](https://www.comedy.co.uk/radio/paradise_lost_in_space/)*, a six episode sci-fi drama, broadcast on Radio 4 in 1995. Two Earthmen, played by Tony Robinson and David Haig, are transported to an alien planet peopled by the "Oblivions" whose society is based on Noël Coward's plays. From a review posted [here](https://www.angelfire.com/pq/radiohaha/PLIS.html):

> Colin Swash, producer of the BBC2 panel game *Have I Got News For You*,
> penned this series, which began as a gentle parable and gradually
> darkened to a bleak and faintly chilling conclusion.  Basically a
> fantasy masquerading as science fiction, it told the story of two
> humans, an idealistic revolutionary (Tony Robinson) and a comfortable
> bourgeois (David Haig), transported by means of an explosion in a
> space-shuttle toilet compartment to a far-distant and unknown planet
> inhabited by the Oblivions, a race of sublimely innocent humanoids
> (among them Louise Lombard and Michael Troughton) who have learned
> English via the chance discovery of a book of Noël Coward’s plays.
> The predictably destructive consequences of the well-intentioned
> Earthlings’ arrival are obviously meant to raise questions about the
> innate corruption of humanity.

Episodes 1-3 are available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uw5zbqZrumg), and the other episodes, including the one where the Oblivions are introduced to tennis, can be found at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/BBC_Radio_4_Extra_20191009_170000).

Comment: Episodes 1-3 are on YouTube and Episodes 4-6 are on the Internet Archive.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/BBC_Radio_4_Extra_20191010_170000